# Regular expression in SQL With in LIKE operator

Tags: sql, regex, t-sql

i try to create a statement to get check if string is like regular string.

```
DECLARE @RuleName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Up to 6 hours'

IF @RuleName LIKE  'Up to [0-9]+ hours'
```

this statement need to return true in any the cases the number after 'to' is one or more numbers.
for example:
'Up to 32 hours' , 'Up to 456 hours' , 'Up to 3 hours'
all those exampels have to get true.
for some reason it work to me only without the + sign

```
IF @RuleName LIKE  'Up to [0-9] hours'
```

but then the expression get true only when there is only 1 digit.

how to fix [0-9]+ ?

thanks

Comment: Is it [Transact-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)? It does not support `+`.

Comment: yes. so there is another way to solve the problem?

Comment: Please check my answer, there are workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Transact-SQL LIKE patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx), `+` quantifier is not supported.

You can leverage `%` symbol:

> `%` Any string of zero or more characters.

```
IF @RuleName LIKE  'Up to [0-9]% hours'
```